# Gvim opening files in new tabs

Tags: vim, gvim

I was wondering how I can modify the gvim.desktop file so that it opens  files in new tabs. Also I want it to create a new instance of vim in case it is not supplied with any files(eg. Invoked from the applications menu) similarly to gedit's behaviour.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be "gvim --remote-tab file1 [file2 ...]".
If no instance of gvim is running, it produces an error message (which you won't see if you're not launching it from a terminal anyway) and does what you say.

This command might not work as expected if you open two different gvim windows and then close the first one (instead of opening new tabes in the second one, it'll start a new window). For more details see ":help remote".

Comment: I look into how gedit works. Apparently it only uses one window with multiple tabs too, even if started without files :D. Guess I was over-complicating things.